Why does maven reactor change the building order?
I have a project with sructure like that:
./pom.xml - parent
./module-1/pom.xml
./module-1/pom.xml

./pom.xml - is an aggregation pom and a parent for ./module-1/pom.xml and ./module-1/pom.xml at the same time.
In this case, there is following building order:
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.332 s]
[INFO] module-1 ........................................... SUCCESS [  1.794 s]
[INFO] module-2 ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.165 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

but if ./pom.xml is just aggregation pom and it's not a parent pom for ./module-1/pom.xml and ./module-1/pom.xml than there is a following building order:
[INFO] module-1 ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.279 s]
[INFO] module-2 ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.363 s]
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.042 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

another one case:
./pom.xml - aggregation 
./parent-pom.xml - parent
./module-1/pom.xml
./module-1/pom.xml

parent-pom.xml - parent pom for ./module-1/pom.xml and ./module-1/pom.xml. pom.xml - aggregation pom.xml for ./module-1/pom.xml and ./module-1/pom.xml and parent for ./parent-pom.xml
[INFO] module-1 ........................................... SUCCESS [  1.953 s]
[INFO] module-2 ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.290 s]
[INFO] aggregation ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.058 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

So I don't understand why does maven reactor change the building order?
I checked documentation and found the following rule:

Because modules within a multi-module build can depend on each other, it is important that the reactor sorts all the projects in a way that guarantees any project is built before it is required.
The following relationships are honored when sorting projects:
a project dependency on another module in the build
a plugin declaration where the plugin is another module in the build
a plugin dependency on another module in the build
a build extension declaration on another module in the build
the order declared in the  element (if no other rule applies)
Note that only “instantiated” references are used - dependencyManagement and pluginManagement elements do not cause a change to the reactor sort order.

But there is nothing here about parent-child relationship.
Could anyone explain why the order is changing?

the reactor sorts all the projects in a way that guarantees any project is built before it is required this says basicaally that children are built before parents.

Technically it is sorted toplogically...

Can you please post the full pom file in your post..
